# 2 User-defined classes for 1 model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, rhtml

Is it possible to create one model that stands for two different objects?
for example:

> I have a blog, on which, I will publish articles on pure text and screencasts with only video.

With that in mind:

I want to get only all posts => `@posts = Posts.all`
I want to get only all screencasts=> `@posts = Screencasts.all`
and I want to get only all articles => `@posts = Articles.all`

And in the view I want to know which class is this post

```
<% if @posts.first is article %>
  do something
<% else %>
  do something else
<% end %>
```

if this is not possible, how can I do something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Single Table Inheritance to achieve this but I'm not sure it's the best solution.

You would have a Post model which has the usual column; body, text and a screencast_url or something similar for your screencast. Now the magic happens by also adding the "type" column as a string. Rails will use this to keep track of the inherited model.

You could then have both models inherit from Post.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Screencast < Post
end

class Article < Post
end
```

Now your code example should work the way you want it to. You can find more information about STI on this [Rails API page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

Your loop could be something like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% if post.class == Article %>
    do something
  <% elsif post.class == Screencast %>
    do something else
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```